# Ubuntu 18.04 OpenVpn client cannot route properly

Tags: 18.04, openvpn, client

When I try to connect to any of my OpenVPN servers, I can ping correctly through to the remote network, but any time I try to browse the net or anything else, it just times out.

I have set net.ipv4.ip_forward=1.

The route is correctly set to have `default via (tunnelIP) dev tun2 proto static metric 50` as my default route...

The same exact config works on the same laptop in Windows, and other laptops in windows, and the server works just fine for phones - it seems to just be ubuntu and mint that have issues.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds similar to mine ([openvpn stopped workng (for me) after upgrade from Kubuntu 14.04 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099904/openvpn-stopped-workng-for-me-after-upgrade-from-kubuntu-14-04-to-18-04))

Adding the following lines to my client.ovpn file solved the problem in my case.

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```