# openvpn stopped workng (for me) after upgrade from Kubuntu 14.04 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, openvpn

I used to be able to use openvpn to connect to my work VPN, but now I'm having troubles. I run

```
openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

where client.ovpn is provided by my sysadmin. It seems to contain private keys so I'm not posting it here.

It seems to have stopped working when I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04. openvpn is now version 2.4.4. I don't know what the old version was for sure, but an internet search suggests 2.3.2.

The client appears to connect (it says 'Initialization Sequence Completed'), but I lose the ability to connect to any server. Firefox, ssh, and even ping either time out or give some error suggesting the server isn't available. However, I can connect to servers (even those behind the firewall) by ssh-ing to their ip address instead of their domain name.

Looking through the log, I see this message

```
Mon Dec 10 16:21:49 2018 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:24: register-dns (2.4.4)
```

However, if I understand this ticket 
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/809
fixing this error involves changing configuration on the server, which I'm unable to do (I've been told clearly I'm allowed to connect from Linux, but I'm on my own in terms of support).

I know the server is up and running because I can connect from my mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following lines to the client.ovpn file after the line that says "client"

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

and everything now works. I got this solution from this answer:

https://askubuntu.com/a/987538 by @AlexOnLinux